# How to run a python script like class in django?

Tags: python, html, django, forms, xlsxwriter

I'm bit new with django and I'm lost, I don't know what to do. I'll explain what I want, maybe you can help me.

I want to create a web page on my site where you input your data and based on your data you get created a excel template which you download. Most basic, you input name of rows and columns and you download an excel document.

Here is what I have tried so far... I have a my_django folder and my_app folder, in my_app I'm trying to create an app to create templates.

This is `my_app/views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import TemplateForm
import xlsxwriter
from xlsxwriter import workbook

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'my_app/home.html')

def create_template(request):
    return render(request, 'my_app/create_template.html')

class CreateMyWebTemplate():
    def create_template(doc_name, name_sheet, years, name_columns):
        file = xlsxwriter.Workbook(doc_name + '_template.xlsx')
        worksheet_data = file.add_worksheet()
        worksheet_data.write_row(0, 1, years)
        worksheet_data.write_column(1, 0, name_columns)
        file.close()
        return file
```

This is `my_app/urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='my-home'),
    path('create-template/', views.create_template, name='my-create-template'),
]
```

This is `my_app/forms.py`

```
from django import forms

class CreateMyWebTemplate(forms.Form):
    doc_name = forms.CharField()
    name_sheet = #selectedcountry
    years = #listfromweb
    name_rows = #imputed column names
```

This is `my_app/template/my_app/create_template.html`

```
{% extends "my_app/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<div class="create-template-box">
      <form action="/">
        <h1>Create your template</h1>
        <div class="item">
          <p>Document name</p>
          <div class="name-item">
            <input type="text" name="doc_name" placeholder="Input document name without spaces" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <p>Select a country for the name of sheet</p>
            <select name="name_sheet">
              <option value="">Country</option>
              <option value="1">Russia</option>
              <option value="2">Germany</option>
              <option value="3">France</option>
              <option value="4">Armenia</option>
              <option value="5">USA</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item" name="years">
          <p>Select a years for columns</p>
            <p> Start: </p> <select name="yearpicker" id="yearpicker"></select>
            <br>
            <p>End: </p> <select name="yearpicker2" id="yearpicker2"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <p>Please input a names of rows... seperate with commas</p>
          <input type="text" name="name_rows"/>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-block">
          <button type="submit" href="#">Create and Download!</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
let startYear = 1800;
let endYear = new Date().getFullYear();
for (i = endYear; i > startYear; i--)
{
    $('#yearpicker, #yearpicker2').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));
}

$('select').on('change', function(){
  let arr = Array.from({length:$('#yearpicker2').val() - +$('#yearpicker').val()},(v,k)=>k + +$('#yearpicker').val())
  console.log(arr);
})
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

In `my_django` app is included in settings.py and urls.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your create_template view, you can handle both HTTP GET and HTTP POST methods.  You can also use Django's built-in form handling to make this so much easier.

New create_template.html

```
...
          <form action="create_template" method="GET">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <h1>Create your template</h1>
            <div class="item">
              <table>
                {{ form.as_table }}
              </table>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-block">
              <input type="button" type="submit" value="Create and Download!"/>
            </div>
          </form>
...
```

New content of views.py

```
        from   django.forms import Forn, CharField, ChoiceField, IntegerField, 
        ...
    
            class TemplateForm(Form):
               name = CharField(label='Doc name')
               choices=[('1', 'Russia'), ('2', 'Germany'), ('3', 'France'),
                        ('4', 'Armenia'), ('5', 'USA')]
               country = ChoiceField(label='name_sheet', initial='5', choices=choices)
               choices = []
               for year in range (2000, 2050):
                   choices.append( (year, year) )
               year1 = ChoiceField(label='Starting Year', initial=2021, choices=choices)
               year2 = ChoiceField(label='Ending Year', initial=2022, choices=choices)
               columns = CharField(label='Column names')
            
            def create_template(request):
                if request.method == 'GET':
                    form = TemplateForm()
                    return render(request, 'my_app/create_template.html' form=form)
                else:
                    form = TemplateForm(request.POST)
                    <use form inputs as needed>
    ...
```

Comment: I got this error `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default'` in this line `country = ChoiceField(label='name_sheet', default='5', choices=choices)`. Why is problem with this?

Comment: I also got a problem with years, it should be created as a list, I got problem with a year1 and year2, cuz it is not a list

Comment: My bad, the 'default' items in the fields should be 'initial'.  I have corrected that.

Comment: As far as the year1 and year2 needing to be select fields ... You can easily change them to ChoiceFields.  I have updated the code for this.  You will need to change the range to suit your needs.

Comment: I get an error with years, `choices = []; for year in range (2000, 2050):; choices.append( (year, year) )`... I have tried to change an order of this, and put a year1 and year2 in `choice.append`. Sorry to bother you. And one question, do i put my script code with or without def function here `<use form inputs as needed>`, od do i create new class with def function?

Comment: Finally, I got visual, but nothing happens when I put data and use button to download, nothing even in terminal, that what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: So, sorry for the delay.  I was recently diagnosed with COVID-19 and have been trying to get better.

As far as the choices go ...  I am not sure what you have wrong.  I did a cut and paste of the code into python 3.9 running interactively and it worked fine.

For the <use form inputs as needed>, you can do anything you need.  If you want to use separate function you sure can.

Comment: In order to figure out why the values are not being set correctly, I think I need to see your code.  What I have shown above should work.

Comment: I hope you are now better, thank you very much for your response. I made it work, a bit differently. I'm stuck on another problem, maybe you can help me there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69013296/troubles-with-downloading-and-saving-a-document-in-django.

Comment: About solution, because this was making me a headache, for now I used like charfield spaces, but user to be able to separate with commas. Now user can input data, not perfect but I need to finish my project then I will try to change it to "advanced version" when everything is working.

Comment: `class CommaSeparatedField(forms.CharField):

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value in self.empty_values:
            return self.empty_value
        value = str(value).split(',')
        if self.strip:
            value = [s.strip() for s in value]
        return value

    def prepare_value(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return None
        return ', '.join([str(s) for s in value])`