# Troubles with downloading and saving a document in django

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-views, django-forms

I have a few problems, cannot figure it out, maybe there are connected.

**Problem 1.1:** file is exported in django documentation and it works, but when I try to rename it, it has some error. I want to be like this `with pd.ExcelWriter(newdoc + 'output.xlsx') as writer:` in order to every file has a "new" name.
I got this error, `TypeError at / unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'InMemoryUploadedFile' and 'str'`

**Problem 1.2:** How to add path where to save?

**Problem 2:** I get to download file but it is empty, and name of document is Donwload.xlsx. I want to be like this, but this got many errors...

```
filename = newdoc + '_calculated.xlsx'
response = HttpResponse(output, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename
return response
```

When I do this, I got this...  in terminal `UserWarning: Calling close()` on already closed file. and this in browser
`TypeError at /   unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'InMemoryUploadedFile' and 'str'`

This is views.py, and if code is like this, there are no errors but I got to download empty document.

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            output = io.BytesIO()    
            newdoc = request.FILES['docfile']

            dfs = pd.read_excel(newdoc, sheet_name=None, index_col=[0])

            with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer: #problem 1 
                for name, df in dfs.items():
                    #pandas code for uploaded excel file
                    out.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name)
                 
            output.seek(0)

            response = HttpResponse(output, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s.xlsx' % 'Download' #problem 2
            return response

    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'list.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`output = io.BytesIO()`
You created here was not used at all.

try changing

`with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:`

to

`writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output)`

Otherwise the BytesIO might be closed by the ExcelWriter, then Django would try to close it again. Giving you the double close error.

Your problem 2 seems to be a type error.

```py
filename = newdoc + '_calculated.xlsx'
```

your newdoc here is not a string, but a "InMemoryUploadedFile", you probably need to access its name by doing

```py
filename = f"{newdoc.name}_calculated.xlsx"
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you very much! I have two more questions if I may ask. About saving documents, is it possible to add to this function or is it better to create new? And... how to render an output for html? something like this line of code `return render(request, 'list.html', {'table': html})`.

Comment: `add to this function or is it better to create new?` I don't quite get this part.

You're downloading a file.. I'm not sure what your HTML would look like. when user submits the form, they should stay on the same page and a download dialogue should pop up.

Comment: Yes, when they upload file, they get pop up window to download file. But also I want to show table from document on same page, also gives me much more possibilities to save document or something else.

Comment: you can't do both at the same time.
Here's what I would suggest u todo, render the page after file submission, then have another button in that page to allow user to download. (or trigger the download by javascript)